# C# HttpClient abort request after receiving the headers

Tags: c#, httpclient, dotnet-httpclient

My feed processing application is fetching third party json feeds in a regular interval and I want to decrease network and memory consumption by caching the last processed feed and skipping the processing if the contents didn’t change.

Ideally this would be done using a HEAD request to compare response headers, but some of the third parties don’t have this method implemented.

How can I make a GET request using `HttpClient` and force-stop the download of the response after receiving the headers, not downloading the response body (practically emulating a HEAD request)

Comment: [HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpcompletionoption?view=net-7.0) ?

Comment: _"I want to decrease network and memory consumption"_ - [**Hold up**](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/1691:_Optimization) - Do you have any **actual data** from your profiler that suggests you should optimize this code, or is this just speculation?

Comment: It does make quite a difference for an application that fetches and processes larger external resources on a regular basis. Say I need to process five 3rd-party feeds, 3 of which don’t implement HEAD for whatever reason and they are on average 15-30MB in size. Just downloading the headers (KB vs MB) every 30min is not a negligible difference and can especially benefit in serverless environments (e.g. Azure Functions) where faster => cheaper

Comment: That sounds fine to me. Carry on.